# Not able to add a where condition after jsonb_array_elements

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table MessagesList  with jsonb datatype column Tags. Data in the column is like ["abc","xyz"]. I need to search in the column for a value 'abc'

My query

```
select value from messageslist , jsonb_array_elements(messageslist.Tags) as elem
```

This returns

```
"abc"
"xyz"
```

I need to write a condition in this resultset, ie like

```
where value ='abc'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_array_elements_text()` to return each tag as a text value, not a JSON value.

I also prefer to define an alias for the column as well, not only the derived table that `jsonb_array_elements_text()` returns:

```
select e.tag
from messageslist as m, 
     jsonb_array_elements_text(m.tags) as e(tag) 
where e.tag = 'abc'
```